# Camera action-Crop not Working Nougat

Tags: android, image, camera

I am trying to crop an image from camera on 7.0 device. I have written the crop function using android intents and exposed my file via file providers to avoid FileUriExposedException.

The problems is after opening camera, crop tool doesn't show up and in my imageview nothing is displayed.

Here's my crop function code:

```
private void cropImage() {

    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException aex) {
        aex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current Device Has No Crop Support", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and my camera intent code here:

```
private void photoDialog() {
    final CharSequence[] imgOptions = {"Take Photo", "Select from Gallery"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose Image Options");
    builder.setItems(imgOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (imgOptions[i].equals("Take Photo")) {
                try {
                    Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "File Saved in:\t" + file.getAbsolutePath().toString());

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
                        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.file_prov_authority), file);
                    } else {
                        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    }

                    camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                    camIntent.putExtra("return-data", "true");
                    startActivityForResult(camIntent, CAM_CODE);

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (imgOptions[i].equals("Select from Gallery")) {
                Intent galIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galIntent, "Open With"), GAL_CODE);
            }
        }
    });
```

When I try to set the imageview directly from camera bitmap, I get this exception too:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

My activity result code:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAM_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        img_camera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        cropImage();
    }

    else if (requestCode == GAL_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            img_camera.setImageURI(uri);
            cropImage();
        }
    }

    else if (requestCode == CROP_CODE) {
        Bundle photo_extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap = photo_extras.getParcelable("data");

        img_camera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

}
```

My crop from gallery code works perfectly though it is the same function.

Can anyone help me out with cropping camera image on Nougat devices as I have crawled every blog and YT video and ntn has worked so far. Thanks.

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created). Please use one.

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you tell how to crop camera image from arthur hub library? Thanks

Comment: I have not used that library. If you have questions, see what support options are offered by the library's developers.

Comment: Thanks, I have used this library [link] (https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiF7u6G4_rXAhXFQ48KHSqwBXwQFgg6MAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fboxme%2FSquareCamera&usg=AOvVaw0B3C2I_4T1AXLkHvF-5xQ0) for the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in your image's name. Try to name it with .jpg as:

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
```

And your error exception come from this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Change it to:

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
```

If it's not work, try my code (it's work for me. And I hope it's work for you too):

```
//Define constants:
private static final int PERMISSION_CAMERA_CODE = 1;
private static final int PERMISSION_STORE_CODE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE = 3;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE = 4;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CROP_AVATAR = 5;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CROP_COVER = 6;


private void openCamera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);

    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
    uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE);
}

private void openGallery() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select image from your gallery"), REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE);

}
```

Then:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        cropImage();

    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            cropImage();

        }

    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CROP_AVATAR && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (data != null) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");

            ivAvatar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }
}

private void cropImage() {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

    cropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 180);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 180);

    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
    cropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_AVATAR);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is working on Android 11.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final String APP_TAG = "crop";

    public String intermediateName = "1.jpg";
    public String resultName = "2.jpg";

    Uri intermediateProvider;
    Uri resultProvider;

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraActivityResultLauncher;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> galleryActivityResultLauncher;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cropActivityResultLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonCamera = findViewById(R.id.buttonCamera);
        buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onLaunchCamera();
            }
        });

        Button buttonGallery = findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery);
        buttonGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPickPhoto();
            }
        });

        cameraActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Bitmap takenImage = loadFromUri(intermediateProvider);
                        ImageView ivPreview = findViewById(R.id.originView);
                        ivPreview.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(takenImage, 400));
                        onCropImage();
                    }
                });

        galleryActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {
                        saveBitmapFileToIntermediate(result.getData().getData());
                        Bitmap selectedImage = loadFromUri(intermediateProvider);
                        ImageView ivPreview = findViewById(R.id.originView);
                        ivPreview.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(selectedImage, 400));
                        onCropImage();
                    }
                });

        cropActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Bitmap cropImage = loadFromUri(resultProvider);
                        ImageView ivPreview = findViewById(R.id.resultView);
                        ivPreview.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(cropImage, 400));
                    }
                });

    }

    public void onLaunchCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(intermediateName);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            intermediateProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.photostream.crop.fileprovider", photoFile);
        else
            intermediateProvider = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, intermediateProvider);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            cameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
    }

    // Trigger gallery selection for a photo
    public void onPickPhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            galleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
    }

    private void onCropImage() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            grantUriPermission("com.android.camera", intermediateProvider, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            intent.setDataAndType(intermediateProvider, "image/*");

            List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            int size = 0;

            if(list != null) {
                grantUriPermission(list.get(0).activityInfo.packageName, intermediateProvider, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                size = list.size();
            }

            if (size == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error, wasn't taken image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");

                intent.putExtra("scale", true);

                File photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(resultName);
                // wrap File object into a content provider
                // required for API >= 24
                // See https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#sharing-files-with-api-24-or-higher
                resultProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.photostream.crop.fileprovider", photoFile);

                intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, resultProvider);
                intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

                Intent cropIntent = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
                cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                grantUriPermission(res.activityInfo.packageName, resultProvider, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                cropIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                cropActivityResultLauncher.launch(cropIntent);
            }
        } else {
            File photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(resultName);
            resultProvider = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);

            Intent intentCrop = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            intentCrop.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intentCrop.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intentCrop.setDataAndType(intermediateProvider, "image/*");
            intentCrop.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intentCrop.putExtra("scale", true);
            intentCrop.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
            intentCrop.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
            intentCrop.putExtra("return-data", false);
            intentCrop.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, resultProvider);
            cropActivityResultLauncher.launch(intentCrop);
        }
    }

    // Returns the File for a photo stored on disk given the fileName
    public File getPhotoFileUri(String fileName) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(""), APP_TAG);
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
        }
        File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);
        return file;
    }

    public Bitmap loadFromUri(Uri photoUri) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1){
                // on newer versions of Android, use the new decodeBitmap method
                ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
                image = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
            } else {
                // support older versions of Android by using getBitmap
                image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    private void saveBitmapFileToIntermediate(Uri sourceUri) {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap =  loadFromUri(sourceUri);

            File imageFile = getPhotoFileUri(intermediateName);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                intermediateProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.photostream.crop.fileprovider", imageFile);
            else
                intermediateProvider = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.photostream.crop">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.CROP" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.photostream.crop.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: https://github.com/bigant02/image-crop
It's also a useful URL.